# learning advance concepts in Ruby. Solution?

Tags: java, ruby, algorithm, design-patterns, tdd

I am ruby dev and have no background in Java. Recently I got interested in learning advanced concepts of Computer Science (particularly tdd, bdd, algorithms, design patterns). But the materials (at least good materials) for this concepts are available in Java or at least they use Java to teach these concepts. I am confused on what to do over this issue. Has somebody passed through this problem and had solution?

Example books:

1. Test Driven Development by Kent Beck
2. Growing Object Oriented Software Guided By Tests
3. Design Patterns by gang of four

There are many more materials in Java than Ruby

Comment: Design Patterns doesn't use Java. Java didn't even exist when the book was written. It *does* use Smalltalk which is a major influence on Ruby.

Comment: these things you mentioned are not really theoretical computer science. However, if you have a solid background object-oriented from Ruby, it could be really easy for you while learning Java; and there's something in DSL (Domain Language Specific) that may interesting you.

Comment: @DaveNewton: Yeah, but the Smalltalk examples are probably more helpful to someone who only knows Ruby :-) Unfortunately, some of the Smalltalk implementations aren't very idiomatic, they are more like line-by-line ports of the C++ ones. Which, considering the evolution of C++ over the last decades probably aren't very idiomatic either, nowadays.

Comment: +1 out of sympathy. Don't know if it's on-topic for Stack Overflow these days, though.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you think the material is only available in Java.

[Design Patterns in Ruby](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321490452)

In addition, learning Java-based design patterns may lead to some very-unnecessary Ruby code: different languages often have different patterns. At the *least*, they may have very different implementations.

[The RSpec Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356379)

TDD/BDD in Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion:

1. Learn enough Java to know the basic concepts.
2. For each design pattern (etc.), (a) learn the design pattern concepts, so you understand what is going on, and (b) look on the Internet for more information on the Ruby way if needed, and (c) practice in Ruby.
3. Profit by learning one language well, another passably well, and most importantly learning how to translate your knowledge across languages.

Then you'll be set for the foreseeable future!